# Roll поворот камеры OpenGL

Tags: opengl, матрицы, 3d, камера, lwjgl

Пытаюсь поворачивать камеру вокруг оси Z, то есть Roll поворот.

```
float rad = org.joml.Math.toRadians(angle);
upVector.x = 0;
upVector.y = 1;
upVector.z = 0;
upVector.x = (float)Math.cos(rad);
upVector.y = (float)Math.sin(rad);
camera = camera.lookAt(camPos, front, upVector);
```

И всё вращается нормально, до тех пор пока центр объект находится в точке 0, но если его переместить куда-либо с помощью модельной матрицы, то вращение камеры начинает происходить не вокруг своей оси, а вокруг центра.
Использую OpenGL 3 версии, как правильно поворачивать по оси Z?

Comment: ну так делайте наоборот, вначале вращение, а потом перемещение и будет так, как нужно.

Comment: У меня камера ни куда и не перемещалась

Comment: тогда я не понимаю конструкцию "не вокруг своей оси, а вокруг центра"